# Bash Get length of variable string whose name is expanded by another variable

Tags: bash, shell

Case Scenerio:

```
start=1

va$start=123

for ((i=0; i < ${#$(echo va$start)}; i++)); do commands; done
```

Error : Bad Substitution
How to expand length of va$start variable using ${#$(echo va$start)} --> ${#va1}

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net You can't set var like this `va$start=123`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
start=1
eval va$start=12345
tmp=va$start
len=${!tmp}
for ((i=0; i < ${#len}; i++)); do commands; done
```

Comment: Don't use `eval`.  You can use `declare` to assign the variable: `declare va$start=12345`.